# Should I delete an accepted answer if there is a better solution?

Tags: support, answers, flags, accepted-answer

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51838862/8746648) about restarting a discord bot, whenever it crashes. I didn't pay too much attention to the code snippet itself, because I understood the problem more in a generic way - more like: *how do I restart a python program when it crashes*.

It was not until a few days later where I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50957031/8746648) in the "Related" section on the sidebar. The question I answered is an exact duplicate of that question, only that the answering understood the problem correctly and gave a much better answer.

I flagged the question as duplicate and thought I'd be done with it, but (a) the flag aged away and (b) I think the answer actively misleads anyone with the same problem, even if it had been marked as duplicate.

My question is: how can I proceed?

- I can't delete the answer, because it has been marked as *accepted*. Should I flag for moderator intervention and ask for the deletion of the question?
- Should I re-flag the question and hope that the flag doesn't age away again?
- Should I add a note to the answer saying something like *"I misunderstood the problem, there is a much better solution [here]"*?
- Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: 3rd bullet is the right way to go about it.

Comment: funny how all answers mention SOCVR when one of SOCVR room rules is "don't mention SOCVR out of the blue on meta".

Comment: FWIW, the Python chat room is fairly active, although it does get rather quiet during the off-peak hours, and on weekends, but even when there's no traffic some of the regulars may be lurking. Several of the room regulars are gold badgers, and are happy to perform dupe-hammer duties.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that sounds a bit like, "Don't talk about fight club." ;-)

Comment: @Mick :) okay but I'm not making that up: https://socvr.org/faq _"Do not advertise or make a reference the room out of the blue"_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your options:

- Leave a note in your answer pointing other users in the right direction, and maybe other users to take the closing onto themselves.
- Reflag after a while.

You are not in any way obligated to do any of these things, but it is commendable that you care about the Q&A catalog's quality.

You shouldn't raise a custom  flag, since that would be a misuse of a moderator flag.

And you shouldn't take it to [SOCVR chat](https://socvr.org/), since it would contravene the chat room's rules (because by having an answer in the question you became an *interested party*).

Do not worry too much all this, though. All in all, you did the right thing. Next time you'll catch the duplicate before you answer.

Comment: I've added the following note to the answer: *"Note: My answer solves this problem in a more generic way. If your problem involves a discord bot, this answer provides a much better solution."*. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything beyond marking as duplicate. Definitely you are not required to remove valid answer.

In your particular case question is indeed look like exact duplicate and you can stop there. You can try to bring more attention to the question to ensure duplicate closure (i.e. bring to meta like this, use SOCVR, talk offline to some gold badge friend,...) but that is optional.

If you get into such situation on other Q&A pair there are two general ways to go about it:

- fix question to match accepted answer (presumably what author of the question wanted in the first place).
- fix answer to match question *as asked*. Flagging as "duplicate of..." is perfectly valid option and you are not required to do anything else in this case. Editing your answer slightly saying "this answer covers … variation of the problem, more general/narrow answer is {link to suggested dup}" could help future visitor, especially if flag ages out without closure.

I general case I personally would go with first option assuming answer is actually valid and not duplicate of some other variation of the question. If you can make edit to the question like "I tried {link to what you think is dup} but it still fails with … " and your answer would be valid for such edit I'd recommend actually making such edit and not flagging as duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

The number of perfectly valid close flags that age away is a shame, really. The system won't let you re-flag them, and a custom flag will usually be declined, which means that the only real options are:

- In the small scale, hope that some 3Ker sees the "possible duplicate of…" comment and agrees with you.
- In the big picture, get more people reviewing Close Votes regularly. ([Huh? What are you looking at me for?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5W9A.jpg)) This was actually the original purpose of SOCVR. They *used* to have weekly events where people would come together and attack the queue, which a clever user could time their flags to, but they don't seem to be doing those anymore.

But in the end, there isn't *that* much harm in a duplicate that's left open. I would recommend option 3, adding a note to the top of the answer along the lines of:

> *Note that there are better solutions available [[here]].*

This will also count as activity on the question, so it may get someone else who can flag it.

Comment: The close vote queue has never been entirely emptied. The SOCVR has never come close to emptying the close vote queue, the most it has ever done is make a dent.

Comment: @TinyGiant actually I think [it has been emptied before](/a/251499/6388243), and anyway that wasn't my point—I noted that they don't do those anymore.

Comment: @StephenLeppik While the "queue" may have been displayed as empty, at that time the criteria for a question to be "in the queue" had been changed to "at least 4 votes or flags or at least one Do Not Close review ", which *dramatically* limited the number of question which were displayed as "in the queue". At the time, using the normal criteria, there were really [tens of thousands of questions in the queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jANCq.png) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/271271)).